# How to resolve BigQuery Storage API 429 Quota Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Downloading data from the BigQuery Storage API and periodically get 429 errors for quota exceeded (error below)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 100, in next
six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
File "", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 there was an error operating on 'projects//locations/us/streams/EgxtbDRaekkwdjhUQWQaAmlyGgJpdygB': Quota exceeded.

The total download should equal around 100 GB.  The error is sporadic.  Trying to find the appropriate quota to either increase it or throttle requests.  Here is the session config.  Anyone seen this quota error and know what quota to adjust?  Thanks!

```
session = bqstorageclient.create_read_session(
    table,
    parent,
    read_options=read_options,
    format_=bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.DataFormat.ARROW,
    sharding_strategy=(
        bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.ShardingStrategy.LIQUID
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are reaching a quota, as you downloading data from BigQuery it is most likely a [load quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs).

I recommend to review the limits and quotas and manage the load accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for input.  Already checked on that.  It is with the BigQuery Storage API and not the load jobs and BigQuery API.  Specifically used the BigQuery Storage API so would not hit load job limits.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#storage-limits would suggest the most likely thing is 5k ReadRows calls/minute given you're getting the error based on the stream identifier, not on the session identifier.  But it's possible if you're trying to control parallelism via stream splitting etc you could be reaching the 1k limit on other calls.

It's possible you'd reach this if you are starting the consumption of a lot of streams via ReadRows in a short time period.  Either the case where you have a single session with many streams, or the case where you have many sessions starting at the same time.

I could also imagine frequent transient network failures could exacerbate this due to retries on the stream.